# Raw development in Lightroom 4.1 and Digital Photo Professional 3.9.x – bad vs. good?

Tags: lightroom, raw, canon-550d, canon-dpp

I have opened the same raw image from my Canon EOS 550D (CR2) in Lightroom and Digital Photo Professional. This are the default raw development results:

Lightroom: [image: Bad Lightroom image]

Digital Photo Professional: [image: Good Digital Photo Professional image]

Why is the image developed by Lightroom so bad? If I manipulate the settings (white balance and so on) in Lightroom, I even get worse results than in Digital Photo Professional (default settings). I cannot figure what’s wrong.

Comment: What are your lighroom import settings? My guess is the Canon proprietary software is applying some development settings which are different from those in LR. What do the images look like when you don't apply any setting in either LR or DPP?

Comment: In LR select the picture, go to `Develop` mode, scroll down to the `Camera Calibration` pane, and see if you can change the `Profile`. Most of the time it is set to Adobe, but you probably can change that to another profile. See if that helps your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue: Had to set the Camera Calibration Profile (Develop tab) to Camera Standard (set as default for all newly imported raw images). Now the images in Lightroom look like the images in Digital Photo Professional.

Answer (score 1):

Take a sample of white shirt - same area in each case - and look at the RGB histograms.

The PDPP photo has substantially different white balance - red level is well down compared with GB, whereas in Lightroom they are much more balanced.